# Is there any way to retain a secondary partition to older form?

Tags: external-sd

I have a SD Card of 4GB. Me Partitioned it using Link2sd.I made an ext2 partition of 2GB for using it as Internel Memmory.Now the SD Card size is shown as 2GB(when put it into computer).Can I retain the partitioned space to older form and can I use the SD Card as a 4GB memmory SD Card?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just repartition the card. Not that you'll lose any data on it, so take backups. Alternatively, if you don't need another kind of partition, you can just change the partition size IIRC. I recommend gparted for editing partitions.

Comment: @SreerajV.S. If this solved your problem, please select the answer as correct answer. Thanks!